# Proteus copy sub-circuit

Tags: proteus

I am working with a small team designing a complex logical circuit using Proteus like this:

[image]

Each member designs sub-circuits and then we connect them together. The problem is that every sub-circuit is designed in a different file so then we want to copy the sub-circuit and paste it in the final design we are creating, but when we do that the sub-circuit is copied but not the circuit that is inside it, I mean, only the symbol of the sub-circuit is copied but the internal circuit is not copied.

How we can copy the entire sub-circuit? I tried copying the circuit inside the sub-circuit but then we have problems like duplicate references (U20 already exists, etc)

Comment: can you reset the part numbers then regenerate them.

Comment: How I would do that? I tried using Global Annotator but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this old question, just like I did today.

In Proteus 8.XX both subcircuit symbol and schematics are copied to clipboard. You still have to reannotate the copies, though. Namely, you have to:

1. Change the references of newly copied subcircuits, so that they are unique;
2. Go to each child sheet, and execute global annotator for current branch or sheet (I found no difference, but my subcircuits are simple enough) with mode set to "total" (the mode being set to "incremental" is why it didn't work for you, probably).

The global annotator always accounts for all part referneces in the whole design, no matter what the scope is set to. The scope setting only defines what part of the design is to be reannotated.

Also, there's a good video explanation from Labcenter:
https://youtu.be/Cr-nB-LjbRI?t=54

Answer (score 0):

You design the circuit of the sub circuit in the child sheet.
first you copy the sub circuit ,place it where you wanna place, then go to the child sheet of the copied sub circuit and copy the schematics from the main sub circuit's child sheet . 
generally when you copy the sub circuit , it only copy it's lay out not the schematics with in .